# Pivot table attach() without auto sort

Tags: laravel, eloquent

`$item->categories()->attach([4,1,2,3]);`

This code inserts record order by 1 2 3 4

[image]
I want it to insert exactly like array order!! 4 1 2 3
How I do it?

```
"laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
```

---

I Add timestamps to it, but again not work.

[image]

Item.php

```
public function categories()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Category.php

```
public function items()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item');
}
```

Pivot migration:

```
public function up()
{
        Schema::create('category_item', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->integer('item_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();

            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')
                        ->on('categories')->onDelete('restrict');

            $table->primary(['item_id', 'category_id']);

            $table->timestamps(); 

        });
}
```

Comment: This is the sort of MySql, do you have any date there?

Comment: Do you use any primary key in the table that it's not the "item_id" and the "category_id"? Otherwise the order you are talking about is the MySQL order of a table without another index.

Comment: i tried this case on 5.5 and 5.6 store without sort 4,1,2,3

Comment: because the table no id column, what about do the query in command console, may be phpMyAdmin auto sort for you, try dd(the result without any orderBy)

Comment: @AdrianHernandez-Lopez Please see my update

Comment: @J.Doe Do you have primary key on pivot table? i use 5.5

Comment: @Mr.Json no, i havent

Comment: @Mr.Json You have to add it, and I think in your case may need to use `sync` instead

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I now do test with primary key.

Comment: Goof @Mr.Json, let me know what gives you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attach()` method respect the given order (Tested), but the order you see in your PHPMyAdmin panel is the auto order when there's no primary key to order with.

Since the data will be patched at the same time to your DB you can't get the ordered list without using primary key `id` in the pivot table.

**NOTE:** You may need to use the `sync` method in this case, It will simplify the edit mode.

Comment: Thanks! after I add `$table->increments('id');` it work. but i must do remove `$table->primary(['item_id', 'category_id']);` Is this not necessary now?

Answer (score 1):

Add a primary key and use sync() to save the data instead of attach, unless you want to keep adding entries. Here is the migration updated:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category_item', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('item_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('restrict');

        $table->unique(['item_id', 'category_id'], 'item_category_unique');

        $table->timestamps(); 

    });
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much. This is true. But I should do accept @Zakaria Acharki answer. Because it answered first. I'm sorry. ♥